# Delete pairs from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a data set in which I need to remove all matched pairs of entries - not just the first entry that is duplicated but both entries.  To add to the complexity, the pairs must be between different columns of the data set.

So if I generate an example data set as follows:

```
SeedRandom[2]
dataSet = 
  Table[{DatePlus[Take[DateList[], 2], i], RandomInteger[{1, 30}], 
    RandomInteger[{1, 30}]}, {i, 50}];
Grid[%]
```

To yield a data set of:

```
    {
 {{2014, 6, 2}, 8, 4},
 {{2014, 6, 3}, 5, 4},
 {{2014, 6, 4}, 7, 4},
 {{2014, 6, 5}, 0, 1},
 {{2014, 6, 6}, 0, 4},
 {{2014, 6, 7}, 3, 7},
 {{2014, 6, 8}, 3, 0},
 {{2014, 6, 9}, 2, 7},
 {{2014, 6, 10}, 8, 7},
 {{2014, 6, 11}, 3, 6}
}
```

I want to remove any rows in which a value in column 2 matches a value in column 3 (please ignore the date column [[1]] as it is not relevant at the moment).  If a match is found between values in column 2 and 3 then both entries should be removed.  Zero entries should be ignored and left in the data set so the resultant data set would look like:

```
{
 {{2014, 6, 2}, 8, 4},
 {{2014, 6, 3}, 5, 4},
 {{2014, 6, 5}, 0, 1},
 {{2014, 6, 6}, 0, 4},
 {{2014, 6, 8}, 3, 0},
 {{2014, 6, 9}, 2, 7},
 {{2014, 6, 10}, 8, 7},
 {{2014, 6, 11}, 3, 6}
}
```

Note that the actual data set only has a non-zero entry in one of the two columns for a row but it was too difficult for me to reproduce this easily for this example data.

I am unable to get DeleteDuplicates to do what I want so am stumped as to what to do.

---

---

My apologies, it looks like my earlier edits did not stick.  I'll reformat the data to remove the ambiguity (note goal posts are not moving - just additional clarification of the data).

Generate example data:

```
SeedRandom[2]
dataSet = 
  Table[{Junk, RandomInteger[{0, 8}], RandomInteger[{0, 8}]}, {i, 
    10}];
Grid[%]


{
 {Junk, 8, 4},
 {Junk, 5, 4},
 {Junk, 7, 4},
 {Junk, 0, 1},
 {Junk, 0, 4},
 {Junk, 3, 7},
 {Junk, 3, 0},
 {Junk, 2, 7},
 {Junk, 8, 7},
 {Junk, 3, 6}
}
```

Output:

```
{
 {Junk, 8, 4},
 {Junk, 5, 4},
 {Junk, 0, 1},
 {Junk, 0, 4},
 {Junk, 3, 0},
 {Junk, 2, 7},
 {Junk, 8, 7},
 {Junk, 3, 6}
}
```

Hopefully that removes the ambiguity of the first column and enables us to concentrate on columns 2 and 3.

I do apologise for the confusion.

I will go through all the answers as I'm sure there are already some that demonstrate a good solution.

Comment: I really don't get what the condition is supposed to be. From the data and the desired result the only condition that I see is when the third element of the first column is equal to the last column.

Comment: This is a very ambiguous question. Do you in fact mean "remove *a* pairwise match (by your match criteria), rinse-n-repeat until fixedpoint..."?

Comment: @rasher That would seem to be the case; I believe that interpretation matches both the description of the problem and the example output.

Comment: Perhaps further clarification if none of the answers fits the bill is warranted. As it stands, perilously close to a close - if that happens, consider editing in whatever is appropriate and getting it re-opened.

Answer (score 2):

By my interpretation of your question this should do what you want.  If you confirm that this behaves as desired I shall seek a more efficient solution.

With your input assigned to `dat`:

```
dat //. {a___, {_, x_ /; x != 0, _}, b___, {_, _, x_}, c___} :> {a, b, c}
```

> ```
> {
>  {{2014, 6, 2}, 8, 4},
>  {{2014, 6, 3}, 5, 4},
>  {{2014, 6, 5}, 0, 1},
>  {{2014, 6, 6}, 0, 4},
>  {{2014, 6, 8}, 3, 0},
>  {{2014, 6, 9}, 2, 7},
>  {{2014, 6, 10}, 8, 7},
>  {{2014, 6, 11}, 3, 6}
> }
> ```

Comment: This answers my question as posed but on further testing with a larger dataset it doesn't quite do what I was intending. What is the best way to offer up a new dataset without turning people off?  This solution will match and remove a pair if the first occurrence is in the 2nd column and a match is found in the 3rd, but if the first occurrence is in the 3rd column it will not find a matching occurrence in the 2nd.  (note you did correctly interpret the first column as the date {2014, 6, 2} for example - and not of specific interest to the problem).

Comment: @CrustyNoodle Since mine is one of only two extant answers I suggest you update the question with the better example and description.  I won't mind; hopefully neither will rasher.  Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw this in the ring, pending needed clarification of the "rules" of this problem. My interpretation (see comments under OP) matches that of *Mr. Wizard*. Assuming that's what you want, this will be *vastly* faster on larger lists (if your lists are <100 in length, probably irrelevant):

```
f = Module[{l = #, ctr = 1, res},
   NestWhile[(res = Pick[Range[ctr + 1, Length@#], #[[ctr + 1 ;;, 3]], #[[ctr, 2]]];
      If[res == {} || #[[ctr, 2]] == 0, ctr++; #, Delete[#, {{ctr}, {res[[1]]}}]]) &,
      l, ctr < Length@# &]] &;

f@dataSet

(*

{{{2014,6,2},8,4},{{2014,6,3},5,4},{{2014,6,5},0,1},{{2014,6,6},0,4},{{2014,6,8},3,0},{{2014,6,9},2,7},{{2014,6,10},8,7},{{2014,6,11},3,6}}

*)
```

On a list of 1000 length using same random domain as your example, over 100X faster than using rules, larger the list, bigger the edge. This also has much more predictable performance - changing the range of possible values in the test data results in little change with this, while the rules-based can get much worse (e.g. tripling the density of duplicates on the same 1000 length list results in a ~500X performance edge.).

Of course, if the interpretation of your problem is incorrect... never mind ;-)

Comment: +1 for jumping ahead to a solution with reasonable computational complexity.  Let's hope it's what the OP wanted.